# Scaling an image makes no discernable change

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am using two different ways to re-size an image, but all three look exactly the same...

What am I doing wrong that no scaling occurs?

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

path = "resources/Shapes.png"
img = cv.imread(path)
cv.imshow("img", img)

res1 = cv.resize(img, None, fx = 2, fy = 2, interpolation = cv.INTER_CUBIC)
cv.imshow("res1", res1)

height, width = img.shape[:2]
res2 = cv.resize(img, (2 * width, 2 * height), interpolation = cv.INTER_CUBIC)
cv.imshow("res2", res2)

k = cv.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Your code works, save the images to see the modified result, imshow might show them the same size...

Comment: @Dinari You are right! I can see the resizing in the saved images whose dimenstions are doubled up, but `imshow` displays them exactly the same. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just putting this here for future reference:

The code above works, the issue was that `imshow` does not always show the true size of the image, by saving the different images, or simply examining them with `res1.shape` vs `img.shape`, you can see the true size of the image.